# Drop duplicates based on 2 columns if the value in another column is null - Pandas

Tags: pandas

If I have a dataframe

```
Index   City     Country    State
 0       Chicago    US        IL
 1       Sacramento US        CA
 2       Sacramento US 
 3       Naperville US        IL
```

I want to find rows with duplicate values for 'City' and 'Country' but only drop the row with no entry for 'State.
Ie. drop row#2

What is the best way to approach this using Pandas?

Comment: `df.loc[ ~(df.duplicated(['City','Country']) & df['State'].isna()) ]`.

Comment: Thank you!! How can i drop this from the dataframe?

Comment: Re-assign `df = df.loc[...]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a boolean mask to get the index of rows to delete then use `drop` to remove this rows with `inplace=True` as argument:

```
df.drop(df.loc[(df.duplicated(['City','Country'])
               & df['State'].notna())].index, inplace=True)
print(df)

# Output:
         City Country State
0     Chicago      US    IL
1  Sacramento      US    CA
3  Naperville      US    IL
```

**Note**: the answer of @QuangHoang is the opposite of this one. I drop the bad rows, he keeps the right rows. Honestly, I prefer his method.